# Unable to use keyDown and keyUp events using selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to do the following, can someone help me what wrong i have done..

**1)** open the site mentioned in code
**2)** Enter the Text "WELcoME" (mixture of capital and small letters) using keydown and keyup events in webdriver.

---

public class KeysUpandDown {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://fleet.idrivesafely.com");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Student Login")).click();
    WebElement loc=driver.findElement(By.className("input1"));
    Actions a= new Actions(driver);
    a.moveToElement(loc)
    .keyDown(Keys.SHIFT)
    .sendKeys("wel")
    .keyUp(Keys.SHIFT)
    .sendKeys("co")
    .keyDown(Keys.SHIFT)
    .sendKeys("me");
    a.perform();

}
```

### }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code requires  2 small changes.

Change 1:
               `WebElement loc=driver.findElement(By.className("input1"));`

is pointing to three Web-elements on the page, Instead use below

```
WebElement loc=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='input1' and @name='pin_no']"));
```

Change 2: Its a Text field, so Instead of

```
a.moveToElement(loc)
```

Use

```
 a.click(loc)
```

So you code should be as below :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://fleet.idrivesafely.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Student Login")).click();
        WebElement loc=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='input1' and @name='pin_no']"));
        Actions a= new Actions(driver);
        a.click(loc).keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).sendKeys("wel").keyUp(Keys.SHIFT).sendKeys("co").keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).sendKeys("me").perform();
```

Comment: @Abhilash T : That was a nice tricky question.If you find above code working please mark this as  Answer. Thanks